# Spring Security Configuration @Order not unique exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, configuration

I've tried to register multiple filters in my Spring Security Configuration, however I always get the same exception:

> 04-Nov-2015 14:35:23.792 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must
>   be unique. Order of 100 was already used, so it cannot be used on
>   com.payment21.webapp.MultiHttpSecurityConfig$ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35c79fe4@1d381684
>   too.

Since my own attempts didn't work, I tried the **exact same code** as shown in the [Spring Security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                   
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

To isolate the error I tried to replace the web.xml by a Java based approach, but it didn't work either. I have no idea what's wrong, is the doc wrong? Can something in my application mess with the configuation? System is starting up properly, unless I register a second WebSecurityConfigAdapter.

Those are my dependencies:

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.2.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.2.2.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-websocket:4.2.2.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.2.2.RELEASE'
compile'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.3.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found the error... noone ever posts imports in snippets. We are using a multi module project setup, and IntelliJ didn't recognise the Spring annotations and used

> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order

instead of

> org.springframework.core.annotation.Order

Since Spring didn't parse the correct annotations, it was assuming the default value 100 for both configurations.

Comment: That's some deep stuff.. :-)

Comment: How did you resolve this?  I have the exact problem when compiling with IDEA.  I have no @Order in my application, yet still it's getting very confused on the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter!

Comment: Use the ```@Order(1000)``` in the SecurityConfiguration class

Comment: @ThomasBeauvais, You probably solved it already but for future reference. Your issue are not caused by bad use of Ordet but the lack of it. When no order are specified Configuration defaults to Order(100). So if you have several classes extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or like me and Journeycorner imports the wrong Order annotation class you get this error.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! YOU SAVED ME!

Answer (score 31):

Maybe you have annotated another class with the **@EnableWebSecurity** annotation. Be aware that only one class can implement this annotation. Hope that will help!

Comment: What if I would like to have another @EnabledWebSecurity for testing purposes?

Answer (score 19):

It may be worth noting, the @Order annotation should be at the class level. This is a bit confusing since @Journeycorner configuration is a multiclass example. My example with imports :)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import com.someco.entity.User;
import com.someco.service.SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService;

@Configuration("CustomSecurityConfig")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(1000)                                                        
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/built/**", "/main.css").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}

}
```

Comment: I changed my order value to 1000, then in my class I added @Order(1000) and this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Usually, this exception occurs when the same bean is resolved twice. 
For example if a `@Configuration` file imports an applicationContext.xml that resolve the same bean, when the application starts tries to register it (in your case `MultiHttpSecurityConfig`) twice, and you get this error.

I resolved the error removing the bean definition from the XML.

Comment: I had the security bean resolved twice. Once being loaded by a `@ComponentScan` annotation that included the directory containing the security bean. And another time by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation that is sitting in that same directory. After removing the directory include attribute, the issue was gone.

Comment: which directory you are talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Putting @Order(1000) on the second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have annotated another class with the @EnableWebSecurity annotation. Be aware that only one class can implement this annotation. Hope that will help!

```
package com.ie.springboot.configuaration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mkyong").password("123456").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}123456").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("123456").roles("DBA");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DBA')")
                .and().formLogin();
        http.csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you copy pasting others answers ?

Answer (score 1):

My issue got solved when I added this description to the Security Config:

```
@Configuration("MySecurityConfig")
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same issue but wasn't able to find an answer anywhere to point me in the right direction. I ended up retracing my steps through git history to find that the only change made was adding @RefreshScope annotation to my class.

By removing the @RefreshScope annotation my application worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Spring security uses [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) under the hood and this adaptor is using order(100), hence spring won't allow duplicate order sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had put the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation on the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, but I also had a separate class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. As the documentation of `@EnableOAuth2Sso` says:

> If there is an existing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter provided by the user and annotated with @EnableOAuth2Sso, it is enhanced by adding an authentication filter and an authentication entry point. If the user only has @EnableOAuth2Sso but not on a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter **then one is added** with all paths secured.

Since a default adapter was being added, I ended up with two, which caused the exception.
The solution was of course to move the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation to the class which extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had 2 tags `@EnableWebSecurity` and
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)`. When I removed `@EnableWebSecurity` tag the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having configuration with `@order(100)` annotation somewhere in you spring configuration. try removing `@order(100)` annotation or give some other order value.

Comment: Checked every java file for "@Order", nothing. Is it possible to have a "implicit" "@Order" like in an XML-file?

Comment: If you see the stacktrace it is clearly mentioning that "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" is having @order(100)

Comment: 100 is the default, no need to mention it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved this error moving @Configuration annotation to class level.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was another security config class that is established in the parent project. I used excludeFilters tag to exclude the parent security config class and I add my config class spring directly use that config class.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.example.parentProject",  // this is the package that have securit config staff
        
},
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                value = { 
                           SecurityConfig.class //which is inhareted from the parent package
                     })
        })

public class SpringApp{
.....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All enabling features should be in main SpringApplication.run(Myclass.class, args);

In my case, I have ZuluConfiguration and KeyCloakConfiguration so I have enabled those configurations under the main class of springbootapplication annotation. it resolved my problem.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@KeycloakConfiguration
```