# How to disable actuator security without disabling it totally with Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot Security with OAuth2. I wan't to disable security for health endpoint.

I can totally disable security or write my own implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and disable autoconfigured one.

But how to modify existing implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (`OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration`)?

I tried to create my own configuration without disabling autoconfigured one, but it is impossible due to `Order` conflicts.

Here is the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. 
Order of 100 was already used on SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9505fc58@13f182b9,
 so it cannot be used on 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc290e2b@5ee0cf64 too.
```

Also, I tried to explicitly set higher order for my own security configuration, but looks like autoconfigured one overrides mine.

So how to override specific security rules without reimplementing whole configuration?

Comment: See [Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-mvc). There is no easy way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement the following method in your

`@SpringBootApplication` class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableResourceServer
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 @Configuration
 public class BusinessLogicServiceApplication extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context =  
    SpringApplication.run(BusinessLogicServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` but messed up with request builder

Answer (score 8):

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
class MyConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

Make sure you are using `@EnableOAuth2Sso` over a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. It's important because it will include `OAuth2SsoCustomConfiguration` which basically copies the functionality of `OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration#configure`.

You might also want to show full health details:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 4):

Following are the possible checks.

**Solution 1** :
Ensure that you are using

> org.springframework.core.annotation.Order

instead of

> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order

Since Spring didn't parse the correct annotations, it was assuming the default value 100 for both configurations.

**Solution 2**:

Maybe you have annotated another class with the @EnableWebSecurity annotation. Be aware that only one class can implement this annotation.

**Solution 3** : Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076087/6572971

Solution 4 :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
public class DemoConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health").permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have your own implementation extending the one you use (`OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration`, if I got it right) and then extend the configure method to ignore your health endpoint. It would look more or less like this

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.regexMatchers("/health",)
        .permitAll()
}
```

By the way about this 
`Also, I tried to explicitly set higher order for my own security configuration, but looks like autoconfigured one overrides mine.`

The way `@Order` works, lower numbers have higher priority so it would explain why the autoconfigured was overriding yours. Doc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html

Answer (score 1):

A quick update as I'm using a very recent Spring Boot 2.7.11. It seems like extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is now deprecated.

Rather I simply do this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurityFilter {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator").permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working

I tried and getting error `Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.`

Comment: It sure does work. The same solution is listed 3 more times below.
You have another issue. Perhaps you have not enabled Spring Security, such that Spring is not injecting the HttpSecurity in your config.

Try to add @EnableWebSecurity to your class.

Comment: Yes, it worked. But I need to change the annotation to `@EnableWebfluxSecurity` and things started working. However, I am looking if there is any other way via application.properties to achieve the same without adding additional class.

Answer (score 0):

management.security.enabled: false is no longer valid in spring boot 2. we need to take ConfigurerAdapter way. Here is my code below when OAuth2 resource server is used.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * to disable security for acutator endpoints.
 *
 */
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurityConfigurer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`management.security.enabled: false`

does not work with spring boot 2.x versions

Answer (score 0):

For `Kotlin`

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator").permitAll()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also use
`management.security.enabled: false`
In your application.propeeties (or. yaml). It will automatically remove any security for actuator exposed endpoints